# Create strawpoll.me poll with node.js

Tags: node.js, axios, discord.js

I was trying to create a poll with node.js for discord using the following code:

```
axios.post("https://strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls", {
    title: "This is a test poll.",
    options: [
        "Option #1",
        "Option #2"
    ],
    multi: true
}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res.id); //undefined
});
```

It seems to be working fine but I can't find the poll id or any settings in the response. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is nothing you can do to change that.
I have researched the `strawpoll.me`-API and its documentation describes requests that fail to execute.
The reason for that lies is on their side.

You may look out for another survey provider.